# Можно ли пулить изменения ветки branch2 в branch1, если потом будет merge этих веток в dev?

Tags: git

У нас есть 3 ветки dev, branch1, branch2. Можно ли пулить изменения ветки branch2 в branch1, будет ли проблема в дальнейшем при merge этих веток в dev?

Comment: *"будет ли проблема в дальнейшем при merge этих веток в dev?"*  --- **может**. А на 100% нельзя сказать, т.к. всё может произойти, зависит от того, что в ветках было изменено

Comment: *"Можно ли пулить изменения ветки branch2 в branch1"* --- если процесс этого требует - то можно.

Comment: проблема слияния **merge** не зависит от того сделали вы **pull** или нет. Если надо делать **pull** - делайте. Если надо слить ветки - сливайте.

Comment: Чё за холивар? Читайте документацию git, там всё есть, merge/rebase

Comment: @pegoopik Да нет, вы не поняли, я специально задал вопрос, чтобы вы зашли сюда и уделили мне время, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, можно пулить изменения из ветки `branch2` в ветку `branch1`, если вы планируете затем выполнить слияние (merge) этих веток в `dev`.

При выполнении команды `git pull` в `branch1` вы получите последние изменения из `branch2`. Затем, при выполнении слияния веток (`git merge branch2`), в `dev` будут включены все изменения из `branch1` и `branch2`.

Однако, перед тем как пулить изменения и выполнять слияние веток, убедитесь, что изменения в `branch2` не противоречат изменениям в `branch1`. В противном случае может произойти конфликт слияния, который нужно будет разрешить вручную.